# Test if a field in csv file is utf-8 python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I want to check if a specific column in csv file only  contain utf-8

I use this code

```
try:
   name.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeError:
   return "error"
```

Is that right?How to test it anybody has test case because i dont know how non utf-8 looks like ?

Python 2.6

Comment: It's valid data because you don't have any fallback logic that would save invalid or any other in your except UnicodeError block, so whatever you want to do there is just dismissed by return "error"

Comment: What does it return from the `decode` function when it comes from a csv file?

Comment: i use u'pi: \u03c0'  as a non utf-8 value is that right ?
when it come from the file it return u'pi: \u03c0'

Comment: @IbrahimMohamed, nope, see my answer.

Comment: You should start at the basics: what is Unicode, and what is UTF-8? A popular article is at [Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Then it will be easy to come up with a byte sequence which is not valid UTF-8, for example `b"\xff"` or `b"\x80\x80"`.

Comment: @roeland when i replace name with  b"\xff" so the code inside the try become  b"\xff".decode('utf-8') it works and return error but when i pust this value in the csv file it handle it as a normal string